# Enviar elementos de un array a la ultima posición si su propiedad status es igual a 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

saludos estimados estoy usando angular con typescript, estoy haciendo un sort() para que me ordene los resultados por su prioridad eso esta funcionando correctamente, necesito condicionar que si dentro de ese resultado viene una propiedad couponStatus === 2 se envíen esos elementos al final del array, he intentado con push ,split, move pero no lo consigo tengo ese código espero me puedan ayudar si necesitan mas información la pude proporcionar (this.coupon.couponStatus, es un modelo donde se guarda esa propiedad que es la que envía el servicio, dé allí lo obtengo) no nesesariamente es la idea que estoy colocando tal vez con el mismo sort() pueda ordenar que ese campo se envié a la ultima posición del array es lo que a mi se me ocurre pero no me funciona, gracias.

```js
.subscribe((response) => {
  this.coupons = response.data;
  const dataCoupons = response.data;
  dataCoupons.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority)
     if (this.coupon.couponStatus === 2) {
                      
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con tu propia función de ordenación. La función sort() acepta una función que compara dos valores y devuelve:

- -1 si el valor A es anterior a B, entonces el orden es A,B
- 0 si A y B son el mismo valor
- 1 si A es posterior a B, entonces el orden es B,A

Entonces, para enviar al final los cupones con "couponState" igual a 2 creamos una función como la siguiente:

```
let sort = function(a,b){
  if(a.couponStatus === 2){
      return 1;
  }
  if(b.couponStatus === 2){
    return -1;
  }
  return a.priority - b.priority;
}
```

He probado la función con los siguientes datos:

```
var misCupones = [
  {cupon:'A-01',couponStatus: 0, priority: 1},
  {cupon:'A-02',couponStatus: 2, priority: 10},
  {cupon:'A-03',couponStatus: 3, priority: 12},
  {cupon:'B-02',couponStatus: 2, priority: 5},
  {cupon:'B-03',couponStatus: 0, priority: 2},
  {cupon:'C-01',couponStatus: 0, priority: 7},
  {cupon:'C-02',couponStatus: 2, priority: 5},
  {cupon:'C-03',couponStatus: 4, priority: 2},
  {cupon:'C-04',couponStatus: 4, priority: 7},
];

let sort = function(a,b){
  if(a.couponStatus === 2){
      return 1;
  }
  if(b.couponStatus === 2){
    return -1;
  }
  return a.priority - b.priority;
}
misCupones = misCupones.sort(sort);
console.table(misCupones);
```

Ten en cuenta que ordena ascendentemente bien por prioridad para aquellos cupones con "couponStatus" distinto de 2. Los cupones con "couponStatus" igual a 2 están al final del array pero no ordenados por prioridad.

Comment: es correcto, en el caso del status lleva al final en ese caso la prioridad no cuenta, con los status === 2 la prioridad no es la relevante, cuando tiene 2 debe ir al ultimo, los demás si deben respetar la prioridad mientras no sea 2, gracias funciono